# Analog input like in a PLC: Thermistor or 0-10V

Tags: adc, current-measurement, measurement, voltage-measurement, thermistor

Depending on the configuration, PLCs can often measure 0-10V, resistance or 0-20mA on the same set of screws.

How to use the same screw terminal to measure resistance of an NTC element, voltages in the range of 0 to 10V or current in the mA range?

Any suggestions how I would go about this?

I know how to measure resistance, I know how to measure voltage, but I'm not quite sure how to combine these. Also it'd be nice to make something that won't break if you try to measure resistance on a 10V signal or the other way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpAO79.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A very basic setup.*

- Leave the switches open for 0 - 10 V.
- Close the lower switch to convert 20 mA to 10 V. (Check the power dissipated in the resistor.)
- Open the bottom switch and close the top switch to provide a current to the temperature sensor which should be connected between IN and GND.

Using PCB headers / jumpers is a standard way of providing this functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that the µC could take care of this. Assume I can replace the switches with TTL level MOSFETs?

Comment: That's going to be tricky. The RTD might be OK but industrial 4 - 20 mA devices are generally fed from 24 V supplies. You'll need to figure out how to protect against a 24 V input when the 0 - 20 mA switch is open.